# Hot to read text from URL in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

i've a url like this:

```
http://local.gogutsi.com/backend/quote/workticket/27119/driver/197?_format=pdf&email_to_driver=1&ret=/backend/quote/workticket/27119/driver/197%3Fret%3D/backend/quote/quotes%253Fquotes_list%255Bstart%255D%253D%2526quotes_list%255Bend%255D%253D
```

i want to read _format value from it.

Comment: i've tried this but it didn't help

$request = $this->getRequest();
echo $request->query->get('_format');

Answer (score 1):

Into controller that rule that url

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 

//class declaration here ...

public function yourControllerNameHere(Request $request)
{   
    //...
    $format = $request->query->get('_format');
    //...
}
```